# Pandas groubpy on substring or regex

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given a pandas dataframe.
How can i do a groupby on the column 'a' such all rows get grouped together that start with the same string. The end of the comparison part is the `_`. (So here y_s1 and y_s2 get grouped together, but not x_s1)

Here is a minimal example:

```
raw_data = {'a': ['y_s2', 'y_s1', 'x_s1'], 'b': [1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
grp = df.groupby(df['a'].str[:2])  ## groups on first 2-letters of column `a`
```

You can do a `count` on this groupby and check that rows starting with `x_` are grouped together and rows starting with `y_` are grouped together.

```
In [1545]: df.groupby(df.a.str[:2]).count()                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[1545]: 
    a  b
a       
x_  1  1
y_  2  2
```

**After OP's comment, a more generalized approach:**

```
## Split the string on `_` and create 2 separate columns

In [1572]: df['a1'], df['a2'] = df['a'].str.split('_', 1).str 
In [1573]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1573]: 
      a  b a1  a2
0  y_s2  1  y  s2
1  y_s1  2  y  s1
2  x_s1  3  x  s1


## Groupby on `a1`(the part before `_`)

In [1577]: df.groupby('a1').count().drop('a2', 1)                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1577]: 
    a  b
a1      
x   1  1
y   2  2
```

#### Another approach without a complex regex;

```
In [1601]: df.groupby(df['a'].str.split('_').str[0]).count()                                                                                                                                                
Out[1601]: 
   a  b
a      
x  1  1
y  2  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extract` with a `regex` pattern

```
df.groupby(df['a'].str.extract('(^[^_]*)')[0])['b'].sum()
```

Output:

```
0
x    3
y    3
Name: b, dtype: int64
```